# <dl> - <dt> - <dd> tags in side by side horizontal responsive view

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have the following HTML code and I want to ask if its possible to alter the CSS code and make a side by side (Horizontal) view and also responsive. You can see a live demo [here](http://www.newsmartwave.net/magento/porto/index.php/demo1_en/categories/electronics.html) in the left sidebar. I already moved them below the main banner and each one takes full width and in vertical order. I want each to take 33% or auto.

**SCREENSHOT**
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="block-content">
<dl id="narrow-by-list">
    <dt class="even">Manufacturer</dt>
    <dd class="even">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <a href="/connectors?manufacturer=634">JfsfsaST</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/connectors?manufacturer=635">fsafsdf</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/connectors?manufacturer=547">fsafsa</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/connectors?manufacturer=633">TE fsaf</a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </dd>
    <dt class="odd">Type</dt>
    <dd class="odd">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <a href="/connectors?type=613">Bfsafasd</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/connectors?type=618">Fsafasg</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/connectors?type=615">fasfs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/connectors?type=614">PfsafasfCB</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/connectors?type=617">Pafsfle</a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </dd>
    <dt class="even">Series</dt>
    <dd class="even">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <a href="/connectors?series=549">safK</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/connectors?series=643">VH Pfsaf6mm</a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS**

```
.block-content {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.block-layered-nav dt {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #777;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
    margin-top: 14px;
}

.block-layered-nav dd {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
}
```

Comment: We need to be able to see how it flows now, so CSS is needed, and if you have a screen shot showing how you want it to look like is always helpful

Comment: @LGSon ok here is the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question without evoking the almighty bootstrap, see the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6b1ua4c/).

**HTML**

```
<dl>

  <div>
    <dt>
      Item One
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div>
    <dt>
      Item One
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div>
    <dt>
      Item One
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </dd>
  </div>


</dl>
```

**SCSS**

```
body {
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
}

dl {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
  div {
    dt {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

This will place all of your `<dt>` and `<dd>` pairs in a single row. You can then use CSS breakpoints to set how many items you want per row, or just have flexbox do it automatically with `flex-wrap: wrap` and by setting your desired width on the `<div>`s like `dd div { width: 33.3%; }`. This is how many frameworks, like bootstrap, do it with their 12-column layout and three breakpoints.

See this useful [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) article for more tips on how to use flexbox.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

Best option to use bootstrap 
It's easy to handle the outer body of the page 
And from that you can automatically get mobile responsiveness

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more please?

Comment: Do you know about bootstrap it's a framework for CSS

Comment: I already have bootstrap there... I tried with inline-flex and flex-direction column but doesnt work

Comment: <div class="row">   <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>   <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>   <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div> </div>